# Will a deactivated iPhone still receive iMessages and emails?

Tags: messages

I lost my iPhone, I say lost because I don't have it. I suspect someone I know of taking it to check up on me. I tried "Find my iPhone" but it said my phone was offline (off?) I never turn my phone off, and I was using it 5 minutes before I curiously found it missing. I called Verizon and told them to shut my service down. I checked to make sure this was done by calling my number.

Can my disconnected phone still recieve iMessages? Everything I have been told and read says **yes**! This is a nightmare! Is there a way to find out if this "person I suspect" really does have it? And is there anyway to stop the I messaging coming to that phone?

Also, does the person with my disconnected iPhone read my emails? In other words are my emails still going to the disconnected phone?

Answer (score 3):

If your phone gets close to any WiFi network it has been connected to before it will reconnect and receive whatever is pending (iMessages, Mails etc.). Depending on your Notification Center settings and/or the strength of your password (if any) the person holding the phone will then also be able to read them.

But

- are you sure the phone is gone and not just laying somewhere you haven't been looking at?
- you still can use Find My iPhone to erase everything on the phone (which will be executed if the phone goes online again)

Answer (score -3):

Nobody can get your info from the iphone if you used a password

Comment: iMessages will appear on the lock screen